# Debiasing confidence intervals by people exhibiting overconfidence

Tags: bias-correction

Assuming I want to de-bias a confidence interval that was estimated by someone who is overconfident (in the sense of overprecision) in his/her opinion. I do not know how overconfident (i.e. I do not know the level of calibration) but previous research has shown that when people are asked to estimate a 90% confidence interval it is in fact usually closer to a 50% confidence interval. For a lack of individual data I decide to work with this. Further I assume that there are no other biases and that estimation errors are approximately normally distributed.

Now I ask for 90% confidence interval for a variable x and let’s say I am actually only interested in the (unbiased) standard deviation an individual assign to his/her estimate and try to extract this from the width of the confidence interval. For a standard normal distribution, a confidence interval is calculated as

standard deviation*z-scoreα.

For 50% and 90% intervals the z-scores are 0.674 and 1.645 respectively. By assumption above the supposed 90% Confidence interval is in fact closer to a 50% confidence interval due to the overconfidence bias reflected in the overly narrow intervals. Is it then valid to calculate the de-biased standard deviation of the estimate by transforming the 90% confidence interval into a 50% CI by maintaining its width and adjusting the z-score down-wards and scaling standard deviation upwards by the inverse amount (that is equal to 1.645/0.674=2.44).

In other words: I would multiply the implied standard deviation b 2.44 to obtain a more realistic estimate of its true value. Is this a valid approach?

Comment: Confidence intervals are not subjective.  They are based on specific formulas and characterized by the chosen confidence level.  A 90% confidence interval is not still 90% if you widen it.  The confidence level would go up.

Comment: You may want to use a term such as "subjective substitute for a confidence interval."  You also may want to cite an example of the very good research giving the "90% vs. 50%" finding.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I was probably inaccurate in phrasing the question. I am trying to infer the standard deviation of a person's estimated value x based on a subjective confidence interval that is estimated by someone who is overconfident. In other words I am asking: if the person estimating the interval was not overconfident, how wide would the interval actually be?

@rolando2: among others Teigen et al. report findings as reported above (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227867941_When_90_confidence_intervals_are_50_certain_On_the_credibility_of_credible_intervals)